# Angular ui-select2 - how to hide until style is rendered on control

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ui-select2

Just came across an issue with angular ui-select2:

It takes the browser some time to render the select2 styles.
During that time (few tenths of a second), the select2 is shown as a regular select.

This results in an annoying flickering from select to select2 when the page renders.

Is there a way to prevent this flickering and render the select2 control in its own style on the first time?

[a plunker to emulate the flickering](http://www.bootply.com/as0oLrMoq0)

Answer (score 0):

Can you just force the original select to have the same style as the final select2?  In my case it's the height that changes and causes flickering. This appears to fix it.

```
select#original {
height: 31px;
}
```